# Doctrine Filter in WHERE clause instead LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a multi tenant application and i'm using the [Doctrine Filters](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html) to filter my SQL by client.

So, when i want a list of my client *Projects* i just need to do a "getAll" and the filter will automatically append the SQL on the WHERE clause, like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM projects p
WHERE p.client_id = 1 #(appended by the filter)
```

My problem is when i want for example the *ProjectMembers*. The filter will add the SQL to the LEFT JOIN, not to the WHERE clause, making useless the filter because will return all the *ProjectMembers*, even they aren't from the client 1.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN project_members pm ON pm.project_id = p.id 
AND p.client_id = 1 #(appended by the filter)
```

This is my addFilterConstrait

```php
public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetaData $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
{
    $class = $targetEntity->getName();

    if (array_key_exists($class, $this->disabled) && $this->disabled[$class] === true) {
        return '';
    } elseif (array_key_exists($targetEntity->rootEntityName, $this->disabled) && $this->disabled[$targetEntity->rootEntityName] === true) {
            return '';
    }

    $config = $this->getFilterConfig($targetEntity->getReflectionClass());

    if (!isset($config['clientFilter']) || !$config['clientFilter']) {
        return '';
    }

    return $targetTableAlias. '.' . $config['columnName'] . ' = ' . $this->getParameter('client'); // getParameter applies quoting automatically
}
```

Any ideas how can i solve this, adding the filter to the WHERE instead of the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Something's not adding up here. Your second query is not valid DQL. Why would you do `SELECT * FROM projects p ... LEFT JOIN projects p`? Are you sure you've built your join properly? Normally DQL format would be `SELECT * FROM projects p LEFT JOIN p.projectMembers pm ...`. Where and how is this DQL built? Is this query coming from your profiler?

Comment: The DQL is correct, i posted SQL to be easier to understand.

Comment: You were correct, i just edited the LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

The more SQL you do in Symfony you will soon see it is much easier to create a repository for your entity, use one for each or share a common repository with multiple entities. Then write your DQL in the repository. Note: DQL is a lot like SQL but it has its limitations.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html

Then you can reference the function.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$data = $em->getRepository(EntityClassName::class)->repositoryFunctionName($paramifyouhaveany);
```